# Android Joda DateTime one hour off

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I have a TimePickerDialog which lets the user pick a time. The TimePickerDialog has a `onTimeSet` method that gets called when the user finished picking the time.
I pass the arguments to a second method, `setTime(int hour, int minute)` which saves the values and displays a formatted time. 
Here is a code snippet of the method:

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormatter = 
java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());

DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = dt.hourOfDay().setCopy(hour);
dt = dt.minuteOfHour().setCopy(minute);
String text = dateFormatter.format(dt.toDate());
```

The Problem is that (sometimes, not always) the hour value is off by one or maybe even two hours. I think the cause of the problem has something to do with timezones, but I do not know what the exact cause is. I also think that the problem is caused by the Joda DateTime object, since I did not have any issues before I implemented Joda time AND because it also gets saved with one hour off.
Any ideas what happens / how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I'm using **joda-time 2.7** (although it might work with previous versions).

I'm also assuming that your program only cares about **hour** and **minute** (I'm not an Android expert, but I saw docs from `TimePickerDialog` and it seems to be the case).

So, if you're manipulating only **hour** and **minute**, you don't need to use `DateTime` class (actually you shouldn't in this case).

That's because a `DateTime` object is "aware" of all date fields, including day, month, year and timezone. So, when you create a `new DateTime()`, it creates a new object with current date and time in your default timezone. And if the current date in default timezone is in summer time (aka daylight saving time), you can have these hour shifts.

*(And I believe that Android takes the default timezone from the device's system, so it can vary according to the device running the code - at least that's how it works in computers, so it shouldn't be different for devices).*

As you don't need to know day/month/year and timezone, you can use `LocalTime` class (`org.joda.time.LocalTime`) which is a class with only **hour** and **minute** fields (and seconds, if you want; *if you don't care about seconds, they'll be set to zero*). And the best part is: this class doesn't care about timezones, so **10:00 AM** will always be **10:00 AM**.

You also don't need to use `java.text.DateFormat`, as joda-time has its own formatters. So the code will be like this:

```
public void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
    // shortTime() is equivalent to DateFormat.SHORT
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.shortTime().withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    LocalTime time = new LocalTime(hour, minute);
    String text = fmt.print(time);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Doing some tests (assuming default locale is **en_US**):

```
setTime(9, 30); // prints 9:30 AM
setTime(10, 0); // prints 10:00 AM
```

PS: the output may vary according to your default `Locale` (which I also believe it comes from the device's system). If you want a fixed format (independent from locales), you can use `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a")`, which also results in the output above (and when you use formatters this way, the default locale doesn't change the output).

Comment: Thanks, very nice explanation. I have already included it in my code and it seams to be working fine. I hope this fixes the problem.